# Возможно ли такое расположение в панели?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть форма, под ней кнопки (ОК, Отмена). Хочу добиться следующего поведения: если форма маленькая и умещается в родительской панели, кнопки должны быть сразу после формы. Если форма большая и не умещается в родительской панели, появляется `ScrollBar` только на форму, кнопки видны вне формы внизу. Привожу иллюстрацию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если делать `Grid` со строками размера `*` и `Auto`, кнопки будут всегда внизу, а хочется чтобы они были сразу под содержимым. Если делать `StackPanel`, `ScrollBar` вообще не появляется. Если делать `DockPanel`, а элементам задать `DockPanel.Top`, поведение аналогично `StackPanel`.

Есть ли вообще варианты сделать такое?

---

Тестовый пример:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="300" Width="400">

    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </TextBlock>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <Button Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,0"
                Content="Click me"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Желаемый эффект — при изменении высоты окна содержимое должно вести себя как показано на картинке выше.

Comment: А если сделать `Grid` с 3-я строками: у первых 2-х размер `auto`, а у 3-й — `*`? В первую строку кладем панель, во вторую кнопки.

Comment: @maxwell Попробовал, такое же поведение как у `StackPanel`, все содержимое уходит вниз за пределы родителя

Answer (score 4, accepted):

За позиционирование дочернего элемента внутри контейнера отвечают свойства `VerticalAlignment` и `HorizontalAlignment` - вертикальное и горизонтальное соответственно.

Если вы хотите чтобы ваша панель отображалась сверху, то установите значение VerticalAlignment равное "Top":

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
```

Comment: Черт, а ведь это реально работает! А я вчера пару часов провозился, уже и конвертеры для высоты сочинял, но до такого простого решения не додумался!

Comment: Йее, работает! Конец мучениям))